# Convert CSV file to a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

My csv file looks like this:

```
Name,Surname,Fathers_name
Prakash,Patel,sudeep
Rohini,Dalal,raghav
Geeta,vakil,umesh
```

I want to create a dictionary of lists which should be like this:

```
dict = {Name: [Pakash,Rohini,Geeta], Surname: [Patel,Dalal,vakil], Fathers_name: [sudeep,raghav,umesh]}
```

This is my code:

```
with open(ram_details, 'r') as csv_file:
csv_content = csv.reader(csv_file,delimiter=',')
header = next(csv_content)
if header != None:
    for row in csv_content:
        dict['Name'].append(row[0])
```

It is throwing an error that key does not exists? Also, if there is any better way to get the desired output!!! Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What's the full error message? How is `dict` initialised? It should raise `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable` since `dict` is a built-in class.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. It should work, still if you are getting into any trouble you can always use [defaultdict](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/defaultdict-in-python/).

```
from collections import defaultdict 
# dict = {'Name':[],'Surname':[],'FatherName':[]}
d = defaultdict(list)
with open('123.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_content = csv.reader(csv_file,delimiter=',')
    header = next(csv_content)
    if header != None:
        for row in csv_content:
            # dict['Name'].append(row[0])
            # dict['Surname'].append(row[1])
            # dict['FatherName'].append(row[2])
            d['Name'].append(row[0])
            d['Surname'].append(row[1])
            d['FatherName'].append(row[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't name a variable similar to a build in function or type (such as `dict`).

The problem is that you haven't initialized a dictionary object yet. So you try to add a key and value to an object which is not known to be `dict` yet. In any case you need to do the following:

```
result = dict()  # <-- this is missing
result[key] = value
```

Since you want to create a dictionary and want to append to it directly you can also use python's [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

A working example would be:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

with open('details.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_content = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    headers = list(map(str.strip, next(csv_content)))
    result = defaultdict(list)

    if headers != None:
        for row in csv_content:
            for header, element in zip(headers, row):
                result[header].append(element)

pprint(result)
```

Which leads to the output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'Fathers_name': ['sudeep', 'raghav', 'umesh'],
             'Name': ['Prakash', 'Rohini ', 'Geeta  '],
             'Surname': ['Patel  ', 'Dalal  ', 'vakil  ']})
```

Note 1) my csv file had some extra trailing spaces, which can be removed using `strip()`, as I did for the `headers`.

Note 2) I am using the [zip](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) function to iterate over the elements and headers at the same time (this saves me to index the row).

Possible alternative is using  pandas `to_dict` method ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html))

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use pandas to achieve that:

```
import pandas as pd


f = pd.read_csv('todict.csv')
d = f.to_dict(orient='list')
```

Or if you like a one liner:

```
f = pd.read_csv('todict.csv').to_dict('orient='list')
```

First you read your csv file to a pandas data frame (I saved your sample to a file named todict.csv). Then you use the [dataframe to dict method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) to convert to dictionary, specifying that you want lists as your dictinoary values, as explained in the documentation.